# How to handle Active Directory exceptions via powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to handle an `ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException` exception in PowerShell when using the `Forest.GetForest` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.getforest(v=vs.110).aspx

```
# Clear screen 
Clear-Host

# Change below as per your requirements

$context = 'forest'
$name='My.Lab.Local'
$username="fake\Administrator"
$password="FakePassword"

Write-Host -Object "Connecting to $context - $name "  -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Blue

try {
    $DC = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext($context, $name, $username, $password)
    Write-Host -Object "Retrieving details of the forest..." -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Blue

    $Forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetForest($DC)
    Write-Host -Object "Successfully connected to $context using discovery account $username." -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Blue
    $Forest
    Write-Host -Object "Successfully retrived your forest - $Forest" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Blue
}

catch [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host "ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException exception"
    $_.Exception.Message
}

catch [System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException] {
    Write-Host "AuthenticationException exception ( Catch Block )"
    $_.Exception.Message
}

catch {
    Write-Host "Something unexpected happened... (Last Catch Block)"
    $_.Exception.Message
}

finally {
    Write-Host "cleaning up ...( Finally Block )"
}
```

The Output

```
Connecting forest... -> My.Lab.Local 
Successfully connected to forest using discovery account fake\Administrator.
Retrieving details of the forest...
AuthenticationException exception ( Catch Block )
cleaning up ...( Finally Block )
```

How to do I get the original failing message instead of giving my own message, like using $_.message or something?

Comment: That is not the right syntax, catch needs the (full?) exception type in square brackets rather than parentheses - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler post that as an answer as it's right...

Comment: thanks @TessellatingHeckler . I have edited my post

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code (or errors).

Comment: @SunMan Screenshots make it harder for us to analyze/reproduce problems, because we'd need to transcribe the code instead of simply copy/pasting it (or open the picture a new window to be able to even read it). The option to upload pictures is there for things that can't be copy/pasted as text. Source code is not among these things.

Comment: Ah.. understood and makes sense to me now. Have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_ should have an ErrorRecord in the catch block. The exception should be in there. For example, use `$_.Exception.Message` to get its message. Of course the error record has more info about the error. `$_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber` would have the line number where the error occurred.

Comment: One question. How did you find these options? When I do $_. I don't get any drop down list

Comment: @SunMan Well you can get the methods and properties on any object with the Get-Member cmdlet (alias gm). For example here `$_ | gm` will show you all the members. As for how I knew $_ was available, that's just experience I guess.